# MongoDB C Driver - Constructing a $or query BSON?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to create a $or BSON query with the following code in a subroutine:

```
bson * outBson = bson_create();
bson_init(outBson);

    bson_append_start_object(outBson, "$query");
        bson_append_start_array(outBson, "$or");
            bson_append_int(outBson, "cpu", 2000);
            bson_append_int(outBson, "ram", 4096);
        bson_append_finish_array(outBson);
    bson_append_finish_object(outBson);

bson_finish(outBson);

bson_print(outBson);
```

but I'm getting NULL as my returned cursor from mongo_find().  I tried to dump the connection mongo->errstr and mongo->err code and they are both empty and 0.

If I take out the bson_append_start/finish_array(), basically changing it as a $and query, it works.  (Unfortunately $and is not what I was trying to do...)

I would appreciate if someone can tell me how I should construct a proper compound query BSON via the C driver.

From Mongo shell, my data is there as following:

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("507d20a72dfd5c5c2534d068"), "cpu" : 1600 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("507d23602dfd5c5c2534d069"), "cpu" : 2000 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("507d236c2dfd5c5c2534d06a"), "cpu" : 1666 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("507d23712dfd5c5c2534d06b"), "cpu" : 2333 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("507d254eef456cca26234013"), "cpu" : 2000, "ram" : 4096 }
> db.test.find( { $or : [ {"cpu" : 1666}, {"cpu" : 2000} ] } )
{ "_id" : ObjectId("507d23602dfd5c5c2534d069"), "cpu" : 2000 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("507d236c2dfd5c5c2534d06a"), "cpu" : 1666 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("507d254eef456cca26234013"), "cpu" : 2000, "ram" : 4096 }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after much experimenting and looking at sources, I figure out that bson_append_int( bson *b, const char *name, const int i ), doesn't actually append an object of int type.

What I got with bson_print() of the above construction was:

```
$or : 4      
    cpu : 16     2000
    ram : 16     4096
```

4 and 16 shows it's an 'array' type and 'int' type respectively... even though the int is named ("cpu" and "ram"), they aren't objects.

What actually worked was to provide an not-so-anonymous object wrapper, such as:

```
bson_init(outBson);

bson_append_start_array(outBson, "$or");

    bson_append_start_object(outBson, "0");
        bson_append_int(outBson, "cpu", 2000);
    bson_append_finish_object(outBson);

    bson_append_start_object(outBson, "1");
        bson_append_int(outBson, "ram", 4096);
    bson_append_finish_object(outBson);

bson_append_finish_object(outBson);

bson_finish(outBson);
```